# Use substring to retain middle value in string

Tags: java, string, substring

```
String s = "John Stuart Mill";
String aFriendlyAssigneeName = s.substring(s.lastIndexOf('-')+1);
```

I'm currently able to remove `jstm -` from `jstm - John Stuart Mill` but I'm not sure how to now remove everything after John.

All data will be in the format `initials - Fist Middle Last`. Basically I just want to strip everything except `First`.

How can I accomplish this? Perhaps by removing everything after the third white space...

Comment: Search for first space or use Regex.

Comment: @PM77-1 First space is after `jstm`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd just use this, should be fast enough, and quite short:

```
String aFriendlyAssigneeName = s.split(" ")[2];
```

(Splits the string at the spaces in it, and takes the third member of the array, which should be the first name if they're all in that format.)

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the following method -

```
s.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
```

This gives a begin and end index, this will help you to easily get the middle of any String.

You can then find the last index with a bit of ( *I dare say* ) magic...

```
endIndex = indexOf(" ", fromIndex)
```

Where from index is

```
s.lastIndexOf('-')+1
```

**Alternatively**

If substring is no "hard" requirement, try using

```
String[] words = s.split(" ");
```

This will return an array of all values separated by the space.

You can then just select the index of the word. ( This case words[2] )

Comment: And how do you know what is the value of `endIndex`?

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
String s = "jstm - John Stuart Mill";
String aFriendlyAssigneeName = s.substring(s.lastIndexOf('-')+1);
String aFriendlyAssigneeName = aFriendlyAssigneeName.substring(aFriendlyAssigneeName.indexOf(' '));
```

After you have removed th Initials, the firstname ends after the first blank.

Answer (score 2):

Why do not you find the substring after the first occurrence of the space in the string that you found without initials?

```
aFriendlyAssigneeName = aFriendlyAssigneeName.substring(aFriendlyAssigneeName.indexOf('  '));
```

Comment: First occurence of space is after `jstm`.

Comment: He already removed that part in the given code segment. Thus, I gave the answer by using the last substring he retrieved in the example.

Comment: You should clarify that in your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion this is a job for a regex: `.* - (\w+)? .*`

```
final String value = "jstm - John Stuart Mill";
final Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(".* - (\\w+)? .*").matcher(value);
matcher.matches();
System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
```

In my opinion using a regex vs substring:

Pros:

- More clear on what you expect as input and what you intent to capture.
- Easily modified/extended if input changes or you want to capture some other part.

Cons:

- Regexes can look more cryptic to someone that's not used to them.